# Simple way to loop through a JavaScript object array?

Tags: javascript

I have an object array and i am using gulp 4.

```
libs:
    {
        a: {
          js: [
            {
              src: 'path/from/a1.js',
              dest: 'path/to/a1.js',,
            },
            {
              src: 'path/from/a2.js',
              dest: 'path/to/a2.js',,
            },
          ],
          css: [
            {
              src: 'path/from/a1.css',
              dest: 'path/to/b1.css',,
            },
          ],
        },
        b: {
          js: [
            {
              src: 'path/from/b.js',
              dest: 'path/to/b.js',,
            },
          ],
        },
      }
```

I need to know all the src and dest values ​​so that I can move files from src to dest.

```
const moveLibs = (done) => {
  Object.entries(libs).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    const types = value;

    Object.entries(types).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      const srcAndDest = value;

      Object.entries(srcAndDest).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        return gulp
          .src(value.src)
          .pipe(gulp.dest(value.dest));
      });
    });
  });

  done();
};
```

This method is successful, but I feel that it is not simple enough, please tell me a simpler method, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! As it stands the title of the post isn't describing at all what the purpose of the code is, it would be good if you could revise it, c.f. [the FAQ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short review;

- I prefer to use the `function` keyword
- You are using `libs` like a global, I would pass it in the function
- If you don't need both `key` and `value`, then you can just use `Object.values`
- Building on that, you might as well use a properly named function parameter and cut the lines in two

```js
function moveLibs(libs, done){
  Object.values(libs).forEach(types => {
    Object.values(types).forEach(srcAndDest  => {
      Object.values(srcAndDest).forEach(value => {
        console.log(`Piped ${value.src} to ${value.dest}`);
      });
    });
  });

  done();
};

libs=
    {
        a: {
          js: [
            {
              src: 'path/from/a1.js',
              dest: 'path/to/a1.js',
            },
            {
              src: 'path/from/a2.js',
              dest: 'path/to/a2.js',
            },
          ],
          css: [
            {
              src: 'path/from/a1.css',
              dest: 'path/to/b1.css',
            },
          ],
        },
        b: {
          js: [
            {
              src: 'path/from/b.js',
              dest: 'path/to/b.js',
            },
          ],
        },
      };


moveLibs(libs, ()=>console.log("Hello World!"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a generic `filter` generator. This way the code does not need any knowledge of the shape of your input and the caller is left to decide how to handle the individual values -

```js
function* filter(t, f)
{ if (f(t)) yield t
  switch(t?.constructor)
  { case Object:
    case Array:
      for (const v of Object.values(t))
        yield *filter(v, f)
  }
}

const libs =
  {a:{js:[{src:'path/from/a1.js',dest:'path/to/a1.js'},{src:'path/from/a2.js',dest:'path/to/a2.js'}],css:[{src:'path/from/a1.css',dest:'path/to/b1.css'}]},b:{js:[{src:'path/from/b.js',dest:'path/to/b.js'}]}}

for (const v of filter(libs, t => t?.src && t?.dest))
  console.log(JSON.stringify(v))
```

```js
{"src":"path/from/a1.js","dest":"path/to/a1.js"}
{"src":"path/from/a2.js","dest":"path/to/a2.js"}
{"src":"path/from/a1.css","dest":"path/to/b1.css"}
{"src":"path/from/b.js","dest":"path/to/b.js"}
```

Above we wrote a lambda that checks for any `t` where `.src` and `.dest` properties are present. Now any `v` that comes out of `filter` can be put through `gulp` -

```js
for (const v of filter(libs, t => t?.src && t?.dest))
  gulp.src(v.src).pipe(gulp.dest(v.dest)) // <-
```

Note using `return` in `forEach` has no effect so it can be skipped entirely. `?.` is used to protect against `null` or `undefined` values that may appear in your tree

Comment: Not a code review of the OP, and a counter proposal with too many Spartan variables names.

Comment: My review is that the code in question has too much knowledge of the input shape. Sorry two variables is too much for your brain to keep track of? It's a pure function, you can rename things to whatever you want